# Let $x_n: = \frac {(-1)^n}{n}$, find $\limsup x_n$ and $\liminf x_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n: = \frac {(-1)^n}{n}$, find lim $\sup x_n$ and lim $\inf x_n$

positive terms are $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}, x_4 = \frac{1}{4} ...$

so, I thought $\limsup x_n = \frac{1}{2}$

and negative terms are $x_1 = -1 , x_3 = -\frac{1}{3} ...$

so, I thought $\liminf x_n = -1$

but seems like answer is 0 (zero)

I don't know why...

Comment: My friend, you are slightly confused. The limit superior is *not* the largest value in the sequence, it is the *largest limit point* of the sequence when you treat it as a set. You have to look in the limit, not at individual terms. For example, if I had a sequence $0,0,28374032952,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$, then I would think that the only limit point of this sequence is $0$, so the answer should be zero, not $28374032952$. In the limit, both sequences are decreasing to zero (you should see this for yourself). Hence, there is only one *limit point*, that is zero, which is lim sup, lim inf etc.

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is a convergent one ! Hence its lim sup and its lim inf both coincide with its lim, that is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition:

$$\liminf x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\inf_{k\ge n}x_k)\\\limsup x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sup_{k\ge n}x_k)$$

Thus, we can see that

$$\inf_{k\ge2n}x_k=\inf_{k\ge2n+1}x_k=-\frac1{2n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

and

$$\sup_{k\ge2n-1}x_k=\sup_{k\ge2n}x_k=\frac1{2n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0$$

---

Indeed, you confused $\limsup$ with $\sup$ and $\liminf$ with $\inf$, which are entirely different.

Comment: but can I write that $\inf x_k $ as $-\frac{1}{2n+1}$ even though it does not include -1 ?

Comment: What are you asking?  Sure, the inferior for $k\ge2n+1$ is that, but you then have to take the limit of the inferior.

Comment: sorry typo :/ I fixed. Thank you I got it !

Comment: Um, no problem?  Glad to help.

Comment: can I ask one more thing.. ? how $\inf_{k \geq 2n} x_k = \inf_{k \geq 2n+1} x_k$ same as supremum.. ?

Comment: @user421044 Because $x_{2n}>0>\inf_{k\ge2n+1}x_k$, and we don't care about larger numbers when looking for the inferior.  For the superior, we discard the negative numbers.